# Design Decision: Keeping a single UsersController or having different namespaced UsersControllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a rails app divided into two general concepts : Host and Association. At the database level a `User` has_one `Account` which has a role (either `association` or `host`)
An `Account` has_many `Offices` if it's an association account or many `Hotels`if it's a host account.

During my development I have created two different folders for my controllers, a host folder for the controllers linked to the host concept (for example `hotel`) and an association folder for the controllers linked to the association concept (for example `office`). Recently I thought of having a `Host::UsersController` and an `Association::UsersController` instead of having a single more complex UsersController that has different conditions when it deals with a User linked to an association account or a host account. But this solution also means two different set of namespaced routes, two different set of services and two different set of views, for very similar behaviors...

Do you think I should keep with a single more complex UsersController and having two different namespaced UsersController a good idea ?